# Does a Summoning Circle's copy get buffed by Spinventoriginality?

Tags: peglin

The description for the [Spinventoriginality](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Spinventoriginality) relic states:

> Unique orbs in your deck get +1/+2

The effect of the [Summoning Circle](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Summoning_Circle) orb states:

> Summons 1 copies of the next orb in your deck

If Summoning Circle copies an orb from my deck, will that copy receive boosted attack power from Spinventoriginality?